Pistorius: “We must be ready for war by 2029”. Why 2029?
CNN:

In another first since the Cold War, Germany this year updated its plan should conflict erupt in Europe, and Defense Minister Boris Pistorius presented a proposal in June for a new voluntary military service. “We must be ready for war by 2029,” he said.

The CNN piece alas moves on to discussing other European countries after quoting that.
I'm guessing, but just guessing, that 2029 is the soonest that Germany can enact whatever they are planing, but just in case I'm wrong, did the German government clarify how 2029 came about in those remarks?

The appeal of 5 year plans. By the way, the original quote is „Man muss davon ausgehen, dass Russland 2029 in der Lage sein wird, einen Nato-Staat anzugreifen“ Something like, he believes that Russia might be ready to attack a NATO country in 2029.

The article directly links to another in the paragraph that you quoted from. This seems to make it rather clear that this timescale is given by Russia if they "will [not] stop at Ukraine’s borders when [they]  gets that far". What more reason are you looking for?

@MisterMiyagi: thanks for pointing that out. Although the latter piece is somewhat more detailed, even having a section on the 2029 statement, the explanation is that's somehow related to Russia not stopping: "On Wednesday, German Defensive Minister Pistorius was quoted by newspaper Der Spiegel as saying: “We must be ready for war by 2029.”
Pistorius added, “We must not believe that Putin will stop at Ukraine’s borders when he gets that far.”" But it's still pretty unclear what he's saying there: Russia will win the war in Ukraine in 2029? Or decide to broaden the war then? If so why [then]?

There was a similar statement recently in the UK, but for the year 2027. From the Guardian: Army chief says UK must double its lethality or be prepared for war in 2027

@Robin: apparently "German intelligence services prepared an analysis of Russian military threats for the government, according to which Russia could attack NATO territory "from 2026 onwards"." But it looks like the German army had a different estimate.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution worth pointing out that 'ready to attack a NATO country" here is in the sense of "able to". I guess their thinking is that russia is going to expand their military capability over the next years.

Politico answers this (date) question by referring to the German army’s chief inspector statement:

“We must be ready for war by 2029,” news magazine Der Spiegel quoted Pistorius as saying in the German parliament on Wednesday.
His comments come amid heightened fears among European countries, especially those in Eastern Europe, about potential Russian aggression extending beyond Ukraine.
"We must not believe that Putin will stop at Ukraine’s borders when he gets that far,” Pistorius said.
In recent days, the German army’s chief inspector General Carsten Breuer said it would take five to eight years for Russia to reconstitute its armed forces from the grinding war in Ukraine — putting a 2029 deadline on NATO efforts to prepare for possible combat.
"In an emergency, we need defensive young women and men who can defend this country," Pistorius said Wednesday.


I cannot answer why he said five years and not four or six. But I can explain why it is not one year or ten years ...
With the end of the Cold War, the Bundeswehr reoriented itself into an expeditionary force designed to sustain relatively small deployments very far from home. This is a matter of long-term personnel and procurement decisions, and a change in priorities will take years unless Sicherstellungsgesetze (state-of-emergency laws) are activated.
Usually the German department of defense has published the Konzeption der Bundeswehr roughly one or two years after the publication of more abstract policy documents like the Weißbuch or the Verteidigungspolitische Richtlinien. With the end of the Cold War, these documents used to come about every decade, but more recently they are comming twice as often -- five or six years.
The most recent Nationale Sicherheitsstrategie had been issued in 2023, and now that is turned into specific plans. Executing the plans will take years, like the decision to create the Panzerbrigade 45 in Lithuania, which is supposed to be fully operational by 2027. That means building barracks, warehouses, homes for the families, schools for the families, etc.

PS -- the Bundeswehr has plans to defend the eastern EU and NATO allies with what they have now. The secretary of defense would like much more people and equipment. The secretary of finance does not want much more debt.

That kind of explains why not one year (too short to prepare for anything) but not why not 10.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution, Germany used to be in 10-year planning cycles in the 90s and 00s, because threats were far away. Now it is back to five-or-six-year cycles because the threat is back.

"the Bundeswehr has plans to defend the eastern EU and NATO allies with what they have now" -- given that we can hardly defend eastern Berlin with what we have now, I have a feeling Mr. Lindner and Mr. Pistorius will have to come to some kind of agreement.
